# Thread to execute for specified amount of time.

Tags: java, android, multithreading

For every *30 seconds* the record is store in to the *SQLite DB*.

I want to execute a thread within *30 seconds* to post the number of records in to our server.

If the thread exceed *30 seconds* then kill the thread by itself.

Comment: give Thread.sleep(3000); where you want to sleep your code

Answer (score 3):

use timer as follows:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
  t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

      @Override
      public void run() {                   //timer

          System.out.println("done");
          this.cancel();

      }
  }, 30000L);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and specifically the `postDelayed(Runnable, long)` method.

This is a lightweight method of specifying some code to run in the future, in your case you could set it to `30 seconds` and check if the offending code is still running.

(e.g. by setting a boolean to true when the code is running) and kill it by whatever means available to you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `thread.sleep(30000);` to sleep the thread for 30 Seconds.
2. Implement your code for storing the data in DB in run() method.
3. After completion of your storing the recorded data use `thread.interrupt();`

Note: Dont use `thread.stop();` as it is the deprecated method.